# Can I solder wall cord directly to servo?

Tags: power, servo, voltage-level

I have a servo which requires 7.4v and a wall power cord which says the output is 7.4v but the connector does not fit that of the servo. Is it safe to snip off the end of the wall cord and solder the internal wires directly to the servo?

Comment: would you have asked this question if the connector fit?

Comment: @jsotola - no, I would assume using the products as designed is probably safe.

Answer (score 1):

First choice: Attach compatible, polarized connectors to both pigtails.

Alternatively, you can solder it up but the result is certainly less convenient to use. I like [heat-shrink tubing](https://www.lowes.com/pl/Heat-shrink-tubing-Electrical-testers-tools-Electrical/4294722456) for insulating wire-to-wire solder joints, one over each solder joint and a third, slightly larger one over both. (My favorite way to screw this up is to forget to push all three shrink tubes over the wires **before** I solder the joints. :)

Comment: Yeah, i also like it when I forget to put on the heat-shrink before soldering. Makes me feel really clever.